# Need to get throught an array of objects with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I need some help with this snippet, I have written so far this code:

```
const parqueAutomotor = [];

parqueAutomotor[0] = {Marca: "Peugeot",
                      Modelo: "206",
                      Puertas: 4,
                      Precio: "$200.000,00"},

parqueAutomotor[1] =    {Marca: "Honda",
                        Modelo: "Titan",
                        Cilindrada: "125c",
                        Precio: "$60.000,00"},

parqueAutomotor[2] =   {Marca: "Peugeot", 
                        Modelo: "208", 
                        Puertas: 5, 
                        Precio: "$250.000,00"},

parqueAutomotor[3] =   {Marca: "Yamaha",
                        Modelo: "YBR",
                        Cilindrada: "160c",
                        Precio: "$80.500,50"
                        };


var i, item;

for (i = 0; i < parqueAutomotor.length; i++) {
    for (item in parqueAutomotor[i]) {
    console.log(item + ": " + parqueAutomotor[i][item] + " // ");
    }
}
```

I was asked to have in the console this output:

```
Marca: Peugeot // Modelo: 206 // Puertas: 4 // Precio: $200.000,00
Marca: Honda // Modelo: Titan // Cilindrada: 125c // Precio: $60.000,00
Marca: Peugeot // Modelo: 208 // Puertas: 5 // Precio: $250.000,00
Marca: Yamaha // Modelo: YBR // Cilindrada: 160c // Precio: $80.500,50
```

Instead I get:

```
Marca: Peugeot // 
Modelo: 206 // 
Puertas: 4 // 
Precio: $200.000,00 // 
Marca: Honda // 
Modelo: Titan // 
Cilindrada: 125c // 
Precio: $60.000,00 // 
Marca: Peugeot // 
Modelo: 208 // 
Puertas: 5 // 
Precio: $250.000,00 // 
Marca: Yamaha // 
Modelo: YBR // 
Cilindrada: 160c // 
Precio: $80.500,50 //
```

How do you suggest to fix it?

I need to respect the format I was given, Thanks!

Comment: each console.log is a new line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store every line in a variable. The double slashes " //"should be only added before every entry as seperator from the car if it's not the beginnig of the line, so I can prevent the seperator at beginnig and at the end of each line. After building a line together just print it on the console.

```js
const parqueAutomotor = [];

parqueAutomotor[0] = {Marca: "Peugeot",
                      Modelo: "206",
                      Puertas: 4,
                      Precio: "$200.000,00"},

parqueAutomotor[1] =    {Marca: "Honda",
                        Modelo: "Titan",
                        Cilindrada: "125c",
                        Precio: "$60.000,00"},

parqueAutomotor[2] =   {Marca: "Peugeot", 
                        Modelo: "208", 
                        Puertas: 5, 
                        Precio: "$250.000,00"},

parqueAutomotor[3] =   {Marca: "Yamaha",
                        Modelo: "YBR",
                        Cilindrada: "160c",
                        Precio: "$80.500,50"
                        };


var i, item;

for (i = 0; i < parqueAutomotor.length; i++) {
    let row ="";
    let startRow = true;
    for (item in parqueAutomotor[i]) {
        if (!startRow)
            row += " // ";
        else
            startRow = false;
        row += item + ": " + parqueAutomotor[i][item];
    }
    console.log(row);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate over your array, using [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get a list of key/value pairs and mapping each of them to a string, then outputting the final string using [`Array.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```js
const parqueAutomotor = [];

parqueAutomotor[0] = {
    Marca: "Peugeot",
    Modelo: "206",
    Puertas: 4,
    Precio: "$200.000,00"
  },

  parqueAutomotor[1] = {
    Marca: "Honda",
    Modelo: "Titan",
    Cilindrada: "125c",
    Precio: "$60.000,00"
  },

  parqueAutomotor[2] = {
    Marca: "Peugeot",
    Modelo: "208",
    Puertas: 5,
    Precio: "$250.000,00"
  },

  parqueAutomotor[3] = {
    Marca: "Yamaha",
    Modelo: "YBR",
    Cilindrada: "160c",
    Precio: "$80.500,50"
  };


parqueAutomotor.forEach(o => console.log(Object.entries(o).map(a => `${a[0]}: ${a[1]}`).join(' // ')));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since each console.log() prints a line, you have to build the string first and print the entire line at once.

```js
const parqueAutomotor = [];

parqueAutomotor[0] = {
    Marca: "Peugeot",
    Modelo: "206",
    Puertas: 4,
    Precio: "$200.000,00"
  },

  parqueAutomotor[1] = {
    Marca: "Honda",
    Modelo: "Titan",
    Cilindrada: "125c",
    Precio: "$60.000,00"
  },

  parqueAutomotor[2] = {
    Marca: "Peugeot",
    Modelo: "208",
    Puertas: 5,
    Precio: "$250.000,00"
  },

  parqueAutomotor[3] = {
    Marca: "Yamaha",
    Modelo: "YBR",
    Cilindrada: "160c",
    Precio: "$80.500,50"
  };


var i, item;

for (i = 0; i < parqueAutomotor.length; i++) {
  let row = "";
  for (item in parqueAutomotor[i]) {
    row += item + ": " + parqueAutomotor[i][item] + " // ";
  }
  console.log(row)
}
```